# Use active cell value in Userform label

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use the target.value in a label in the Userform? No matter what I've tried I get an error. (Run-time "438": Object doesn't support property or method )

I would like the userform to show when a cell number is changed:

My Worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range


    Set KeyCells = Range("D8:D12")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then

        UserForm1.Show

End If
End Sub
```

My Userform code the way I would imagine it should work (But it doesn't work):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Label1.Caption = Worksheets("Personal Barrier").Target.Offset(0, -1).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what error do you get?

Comment: Run-time "438": Object doesn't support property or method

Comment: There is no `Target` property in `Worksheet` object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Target` property in `Worksheet` object. You can set label in `Worksheet_Change` method:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("D8:D12")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
        UserForm1.Show

    End If
End Sub
```